# Java: How to keep raw UTF-8 data of string?

Tags: java, utf-8, xmpp

I'm working on XMPP (Jabber) client in Java and I want to connect to server via SASL. After some research I found this [site](http://deusty.blogspot.com/2007/09/example-please.html) that explains whole authentication mechanism.

Problem is when I'm supposed to keep result of md5 hashing as raw data:

> *Here's the trick - normally when you hash stuff you get a result in hex values. But we don't want this result as a string of hex values! We need to keep the result as raw data! If you were to do a hex dump of this data you'd find it to be "3a4f5725a748ca945e506e30acd906f0". But remeber, we need to operate on it's raw data, so don't convert it to a string.*

How can this be achieved in Java? And if I'm not supposed to convert result to String, how should I work with it afterwards when I need to use it in another md5 hashing?

---

*And just FYI this is part of my school project (it's not mandatory and no, I'm not cheating by asking for help). And I'm saying that because I'm forbidden to use **nonstandard libraries** of JDK (for example com.sun.org.apache).*

Comment: Could you add a bit of code? Something along the lines of "I need result of function X, but in format Y". Currently it's not clear what exactly you need "raw data" (Byte[]) from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone wanted the code that computes **response** String for XMPP SASL challenge query, here it is:

```
private static byte[] combineByteArrays(byte[] a, byte[] b) { // combines two byte[] arrays
    byte[] result = new byte[a.length + b.length];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length);
    for (int i = a.length; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = b[i-a.length];            
    }
    return result;
}

private static String byteArrayToHex(byte[] array) {  // returns hex representation of byte[] array
    String resultStr = "";
    for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        resultStr += Integer.toString( ( array[i] & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring( 1 );
    }
    return resultStr;
}

private static String computeResponse(String username, String password, String realm, String nonce, String qop, String cnonce, String digest_uri, String nc) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {  // computes response for challenge query of XMPP server
    MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    final byte[] part1 = md5.digest(combineByteArrays(md5.digest((username + ":" + realm + ":" + password).getBytes()), (":" + nonce + ":" + cnonce).getBytes()));
    final byte[] part2 = md5.digest(combineByteArrays("AUTHENTICATE:".getBytes(), digest_uri.getBytes()));
    final byte[] temp = combineByteArrays(byteArrayToHex(part1).getBytes(), (":" + nonce + ":" + nc + ":" + cnonce + ":" + qop + ":").getBytes());
    final byte[] part3  = md5.digest(combineByteArrays(temp, byteArrayToHex(part2).getBytes()));
    return byteArrayToHex(part3);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    /* example data from http://deusty.blogspot.com/2007/09/example-please.html */
    String username = "test";
    String password = "secret";
    String realm = "osXstream.local";
    String nonce = "392616736";
    String qop = "auth";
    String cnonce = "05E0A6E7-0B7B-4430-9549-0FE1C244ABAB";
    String digest_uri = "xmpp/osXstream.local";
    String nc = "00000001";        

    /* prints out "37991b870e0f6cc757ec74c47877472b" */
    System.out.println(computeResponse(username, password, realm, nonce, qop, cnonce, digest_uri, nc));  
}
```

**I hope it helps.**

Answer (score 1):

The `MessageDigest` class in Java can be used to give you a MD5 hasher.  The MD5 hasher you get from it takes a `byte[]` and returns a `byte[]`.  Just keep around the returned `byte[]`.  Looking at the web page you gave a link to, it looks like you'll have be making other `byte[]` and will be copying intermediate results into pieces of other `byte[]` and then hashing those.

Comment: Now I'm completely lost. I tried this: `String input = "testing";` `MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");` `byte[] result = md5.digest(input.getBytes());` and if I print out the result it comes out as complete garbage. And if i try to print it out byte by byte it seems like some of the bytes are negative which seems odd to me...

Comment: @MyFlower: Yeah, it is complete garbage. This is the way how a hash works. If you want to look at it, convert it to hexadecimal or base64 or something, but to work with it, you'll use the `byte[]`.

Comment: I love you! :-D I was so close to the right solution, but you pointed me in right direction. Thank you!

Comment: @MyFlower: Also, the output from MessageDigest is most likely no valid `UTF-8` encoding of a Java string, so *raw UTF-8 data* is not the right word.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but i don't really catch what you mean by "raw data".

Actually if you have a byte stream or something raw like that, instead of converting it to a hex String, just keep using that byte stream/array...

I guess it's not advised to use string because if you convert the bytes to an hexadecimal representation string, you could have the temptation to use myHexString.getBytes("UTF-8") that would not return the appropriate byte array you would expect.